# Grammar error in notification in Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, wording

In the Android app, the notification that is displayed when you up-vote two answers too quickly has a grammar error. There does not appear to be a space between the `1` and `seconds`. This message was displayed when I did the following:

1. On a question with more than one answer (probably easiest on a question with multiple short answers)
2. Up-vote two different answers very quickly (probably within a second of each other)
3. Notification appears if you voted twice too quickly

Also, and this just might be my personal opinion, I think it should be worded a little better. Instead of `You perform this action for another 1 seconds`, I think it would make more sense if it read `You can't perform this action for another 1 second` or `You cannot perform this action for another 1 second`. The way it is currently worded makes it sound like your are doing something for another second but really, you can't do something for another second.

[image]

I'm on version 1.0.3

Comment: The missing space is bug for sure, as for wording most likely a bug too. (Bug in wording)

Comment: It's not a wording bug; it's a threat. "You go on like this for another ████ing second, I'm going to █████ your █████ face!"

Comment: @ShadowWizard thank you for clarifying that.

Comment: Oh, and not to forget the "1 seconds" - with Jeff and his giant S gone we can safely ask to make it "1 second". ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A fix for this went out in the most recent API deploy.